# How to get nested json object for given form details?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-model

I am trying to get `json` object and I have tried it but it's coming like in a plain json format, but I need it like in something `nested json` format like what I explained in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/Lf3m1ocb/). How can I achieve it ? Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your form html with

```
<form action="" method="post" id="formid" name="testForm">
    First Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="formData.testing.Fname" maxlength="50" size="12" /><br/>
    <br/> Last Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="formData.testing.Lname" maxlength="50" size="12" /><br/>
    <br/>
     Middle Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="formData.testing.Mname" maxlength="50" size="12" /><br/>
    <br/> Education:
    <br/>
    <select ng-model="formData.testing.Education">
      <option value="HighSchool">HighSchool</option>
      <option value="College">College</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/> Age:
    <input type="text" ng-model="formData.testing.Age" maxlength="2" size="10" /><br/>
    <br/> University:
    <br/>
    <select ng-model="formData.University">
      <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
      <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Companies:<br/>
<select ng-model="formData.companies">
<option value="X">X</option>
<option value="Y">Y</option>
<option value="Z">Z</option></select><br/>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" ng-click="serialize($event)" />
    </p>
  </form>
```

that means the data you want within testing node put it in the same format while binding it i.e. replace like `ng-model="formData.Fname"` with `ng-model="formData.testing.Fname"`

Comment: thanks for your reply, it is working fine as per my requirements. Thanks you !!

Comment: I have one query that how can I select any dropdown option by default and any default text value for any First Name/Last Name/Middle Name in the above fiddle/html ?

Comment: Initialize the scope values inside controller. Checkout https://jsfiddle.net/KishoreBarik/Lf3m1ocb/2/ . It's based on your old fiddle. So get idea and modify as per new changes

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.serialize = function($event){
var testing = [
    {'Fname':$scope.formData.Fname},
  {'Lname':$scope.formData.Lname},
  {'Mname':$scope.formData.Mname},
  {'Education':$scope.formData.Education},
  {'Age':$scope.formData.Age},
];
$scope.formData = {
'testing' : testing, 
'University' : $scope.formData.University,
'Companies' : $scope.formData.companies,
};
console.log($scope.formData)
alert(JSON.stringify($scope.formData))
console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.formData));
$event.preventDefault()
```

}

use this code.